# EF6 Update DBContext Class for new Password

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to update my EF6 DbContext class to modify password in the connection string that it gets from web.config before calling the base class constructor with the new connection string.
EF Code First Implementation with Migrations enabled.

I added a static constructor inside DBContext class that gets connection string from web.config and updates the password in the connection string into a new class variable.
This variable is then used to call base constructor.

I am getting the following error when I do that:
**Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor**

I could not resolve it except when I **remove partial** keyword in DBContext class it works.
What is a good solution to the error message and what happens if I remove partial keyword from DbContext Class?

```
public class AssetContext : DbContext 
{
    public static string _assetContextConnectionString = "";
    
    static AssetContext()
    {
        _assetContextConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssetContext"].ConnectionString;
        _assetContextConnectionString = _assetContextConnectionString.Replace("XXXXX", "New");  
    }

    public AssetContext()
        : base(_assetContextConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AssetContext>(null);
    }
```

Comment: The error says `Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor`.  Your DbContext is not a controller.

Comment: Please, provide the exact error message. It shoud state whic controller is causing the problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even though error message said the above, but postman is showing me another error that I took care of. I am testing now and will repost update soon.